# How to refactor those basic classes (PyQt5)

Tags: python, oop, pyqt, refactoring

I am learning PyQt5 and I tried to create a extended widgets.
I am also learning OOP so I lack experience for this project.

My final goal is to have master widgets that can disable/enable some slave widgets.
So far I need check and radio buttons.

So I tried to create an abstract class that contains the extended behavior of the widgets (the management of the state of the slaves widgets):

```
class QDisablingWidget():
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self):
        self.slaveWidgets = []
        self.slaveStateWhenMasterIsEnabled = {}

    def addSlaveWidget(self, slaveWidget, isEnabledWhenMasterIsEnabled=True):
        [...]
    def updateSlaveStatus(self):
        [...]
```

Then I create my extended widget classes:

```
class QDisablingCheckBox(QtWidgets.QCheckBox, QDisablingWidget):
    def __init__(self, text=None, parent=None, isInMutexGroup=False):
        super(QtWidgets.QCheckBox, self).__init__()
        super(QDisablingWidget, self).__init__()
        if text:
            self.setText(text)
        if parent:
            self.setParent(parent)
        self.isInMutexGroup = isInMutexGroup

        # Click signal handling
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.updateSlaveStatus)


class QDisablingRadioButton(QtWidgets.QRadioButton, QDisablingWidget):
    def __init__(self, text=None, parent=None, isInMutexGroup=False):
        super(QtWidgets.QRadioButton, self).__init__()
        super(QDisablingWidget, self).__init__()
        if text:
            self.setText(text)
        if parent:
            self.setParent(parent)
        self.isInMutexGroup = isInMutexGroup

        # Click signal handling
        self.toggled.connect(self.updateSlaveStatus)
```

You can already see the problem:
I need to connect my `self.updateSlaveStatus` to the correct signals (`stateChanged` and `toggled`) so I added it in the constructor of the derived classes.
Recently I also added the `isInMutexGroup` argument for some implementation reasons and I realize that I am duplicating the code in both derived classes...

It is the first time I try to use OOP "for real" (first attempt of multiple inheritance and abstract class), so even if I know I am breaking the beauty of the OOP concept, I don't know what to do to get a nice class hierarchy...

So basically, I am looking for a solution on this example. But I am also looking for guidelines, general advice, tutorials, etc. Actually anything that could help me!

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I got a downvote for that question, I think some beginners could be interested by the solution I found:

I have my extension abstract class like that:

```
class QDisablingWidget(QtCore.QObject):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self, isInMutexGroup=False, **kwds):
        [...]
```

Then I can derive class like that:

```
class QDisablingCheckBox(QtWidgets.QCheckBox, QDisablingWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        super().__init__(**kwds)
        # On click signal handling
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.updateSlaveStatus)
```

and

```
class QDisablingRadioButton(QtWidgets.QRadioButton, QDisablingWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        super().__init__(**kwds)
        # On click signal handling
        self.toggled.connect(self.updateSlaveStatus)
```

Finally, when I use the classes I need to create object like that:

```
disablingRadioBut = QWidgets.QDisablingRadioButton(text="My button",
                                                   parent=self,
                                                   isInMutexGroup=True)
```

I.e I must use keywords explicitly so that each constructors will eat the kewords the use/know.
Thanks to this approach I have maximum reusability of my extension class.

I got this solution here:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/multiinheritance.html

And more details here:
http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

A very nice article!